# Trait object's method which accepts several numeric types

Tags: rust, traits

I want a trait object's method which accepts several numeric types, all of which will be converted to `f64`. The following does not compile, since `NumCast` implements the `Sized` trait:

```
use num_traits::NumCast;

pub trait Grapher {
    fn add(&mut self, key: &str, number: &dyn NumCast);
    fn show(&self);
}
```

A generic version of such method disables `Grapher` for object creation:

```
fn agregar<T: NumCast>(&mut self, key: &str, number: &T);
```

My solution was to create another trait:

```
pub trait F64Convertible {
    fn convert(&self) -> f64;
}

impl F64Convertible for i32 {
    fn convert(&self) -> f64 {
        *self as f64
    }
}

impl F64Convertible for u8 {
    fn convert(&self) -> f64 {
        *self as f64
    }
}
// same for many numeric types...

// use the trait:
pub trait Grapher {
    fn add(&mut self, key: &str, number: &dyn F64Convertible);
    fn show(&self);
}
```

I'd like to avoid the repetitive conversion functions in my code, maybe leveraging `NumCast` or a similar trait.

Comment: What's wrong with accepting one type and then using `as` when calling the function to cast variables?

Comment: There is nothing wrong, it is more a theoretical question. The callers may have numeric values of several types. I'd like to accept a range of types (for example those implementing NumCast) avoiding the conversion on the caller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in this particular case, it would not be really helpful to accept `dyn NumCast`, because `NumCast` only has a `fn from(self)` that constructs a new number from another one (whereas you probably want to provide a number).

Now, in this example, you could possibly get away with just require `ToPrimitive`:

```
fn add(&mut self, key: &str, number: &dyn ToPrimitive) {
    number.to_f64();
}
```

But before going with that solution I would ask myself if it wouldn't make things easier if your function simply accepted an `Option<f64>` (or even `f64`). This way, it is clear that your function actually works on `f64` and the callers just have to be aware of that. Moreover, simply accepting the type actually required by a function involves some casts at the call site, but generally leads to fewer casts at run time.

Comment: It works, thanks. Seems to me that for all/most Sized traits there should be a non-Sized trait (like toPrimitive) which implements most of the former trait's operations, in order to allow dynamic dispatch.